# Pass arguments or parameters to a class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arguments, parameter-passing, gsap

I am sorry if I do not have the terminology correct, but I am trying to pass arguments to change the options in a JavaScript class and I do not know how. I want to be able to change the background and fill properties when initiating it. My tech stack is node.js, webpack, gulp, javascript, pug, and gasp.

Here is the object that I need to pass to:

```
export default class WaveSingle {
    constructor(container, options = {}) {
        this.container = container;

        this.opts = {
            background: 0x000000,
            fill: 0xffffff,
            ...options,
        };
```

Initiating the object:

```
import {Component} from 'bona';
import {magicBatchSlideElementAppear} from '../lib/transitions';
import WaveSingle from '../lib/WaveSingle';

export default class FormHero extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);

        this.scene = this.el.querySelector('.form-hero-bg-scene');
        this.col = this.el.querySelectorAll('.form-hero-grid-col');
    }

    async onInit() {
        await document.fonts.ready;

        this.initWave();
    }

    initWave() {
        this.wave = new WaveSingle(this.scene);
    }
}
```

How do I change the properties of background and fill in WaveSingle via:

```
this.wave = new WaveSingle(this.scene);
```

Comment: something like this? `this.wave = new WaveSingle(this.scene, { background: 0xffffff });`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author solved the problem without answers